# proprietary shell command within bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to put together a bash script that among other things, enters md shell (a shell used by our pbx system) to run a command.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash 
mdsh
examplecommand; >> /var/log/test.log
exit
```

This will open md shell, but the script does not continue to the next line.  What is the simplest way to accomplish this, within bash if possible?  Thank you much.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work, because the `mdsh` presumably just sits there waiting for input, and until it exits, the `bash` script won't continue.

If `mdsh` is a remotely normal shell, you should be able to pass the commands to the custom shell via a [heredoc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) instead:

```
mdsh <<EOF
examplecommand; >> /var/log/test.log
exit
EOF
```